# Regex pattern for matching entire word if it have a ; in the word in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove some garbage from a text and would like to remove all words that have "," in the middle of 2 characters. I have tried both expressions bellow

```
r'\s.*;.*\s' and r'\s.*\W.*\s'
```

in this text

```
'the cat as;asas was wjdwi;qs at home'
```

And it seems to miss some white spaces, returning

```
'cat as;asas was wjdwi;qs at '
```

When I needed

```
'the cat was at home'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution is to not use a regex:

```
s = 'the cat as;asas was wjdwi;qs at home'
res = ' '.join(w for w in s.split() if ';' not in w)
# the cat was at home
```

You might need a more complicated check, but split it into "words" first, then apply a check to each "word"...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
re.sub(r'(?i)\s?[a-z]+;[a-z]+\s?', ' ', yourstr)
```

Comment: More succinct way might be this: `re.sub(r'\s?\w+;\w+\s?', ' ', yourstr)`

Comment: @renfredxh: it doesn't since the `\w` character class contains digits and underscore too.